# change a dictionary of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries like this small example:

small example:

```
dict = {1: {'A': 8520, 'C': 5772, 'T': 7610, 'G': 5518}, 2: {'A': 8900, 'C': 6155, 'T': 6860, 'G': 5505}}
```

I want to make an other dictionary of dictionaries in which instead of absolute numbers I would have the frequency of every number in every sub-dictionary. for example for the 1st inner dictionary I would have the following sub-dictionary:

```
1: {'A': 31.25, 'C': 21, 'T': 27.75, 'G': 20}
```

here is the expected output:

```
dict2 = {1: {'A': 31.25, 'C': 21, 'T': 27.75, 'G': 20}, 2: {'A': 32.5, 'C': 22.50, 'T': 25, 'G': 20}}
```

I am trying to do that in python using the following command:

```
dict2 = {}
for item in  dict.items():
    freq = item.items/sum(item.items())
    dict2[] = freq
```

but the results of this code is not what I want. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: `item.item` is a built-in method where as `item.items()` is a `dict_items` view, neither of which are really usable on their own.  The first will need to be called (`item.items()`) and the second will need to be iterated (like you did with the for loop).  Also using `dict` as a variable name is not recommended as it shadows the built-in keyword `dict` used to create dictionary objects.  Try using `dct` or `my_dict` instead.  Also, how did you get to the "frequencies" in your expected output? e.g. for `1` why is `'A': 31.25` not `31`, and `'G': 20` not `20.25`? The rounding detail is unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to process the inner dictionaries without modifying the keys of the big one. Outsource the frequency into a function:

```
def get_frequency(d):
    total = sum(d.values())
    return {key: value / total * 100 for key, value in d.items()}
```

Then use a dict comprehension to apply the function on all your sub dictionaries:

```
dict2 = {key: get_frequency(value) for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

Note that I added a `* 100`, it appears from your output that you are looking for percents from `0-100` and not a `float` from `0-1`.

Edit:

If you're using python2 `/` is integer division so add a `float` like so:

```
return {key: float(value) / total * 100 for key, value in d.items()}
```

Comment: all frequencies are 0

Comment: Are you on python2?

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
dct = {1: {'A': 8520, 'C': 5772, 'T': 7610, 'G': 5518}, 2: {'A': 8900, 'C': 6155, 'T': 6860, 'G': 5505}}

result = {}
for key, d in dct.items():
    total = sum(d.values())
    result[key] = {k : a / total for k, a in d.items()}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{1: {'C': 0.21050328227571116, 'T': 0.2775346462436178, 'G': 0.2012399708242159, 'A': 0.31072210065645517}, 2: {'C': 0.22447118891320203, 'T': 0.25018234865062, 'G': 0.20076586433260393, 'A': 0.32458059810357404}}
```

Comment: all frequencies are 0

Comment: What do you mean all frequencies are 0?

Comment: {1: {'A': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'T': 0.0, 'G': 0.0}, 2: {'A': 0.0, 'C': 0.0, 'T': 0.0, 'G': 0.0}}

Comment: Did you run the above example?

Comment: Could you show me the input data that leads to all frequencies are 0?

Comment: dct = {1: {'A': 8520, 'C': 5772, 'T': 7610, 'G': 5518}, 2: {'A': 8900, 'C': 6155, 'T': 6860, 'G': 5505}}

Comment: That is the input from your post